# Create-React-App ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, commonjs

I have a react app that is created using https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app 
but I'd like to import some code that is shared with a NodeJs project (and thus use the `commonjs` syntax)

The code is exported with

```
exports.Agreement = agreement
```

When I import that code in my project using

```
const Agreement = require('../../common/model/agreement').Agreement
```

I start getting this error in my browser:

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined
Module.../common/model/agreement.js
/Users/teone/Sites/cla-manager/common/model/agreement.js:217
  214 | 
  215 | export const AgreementType = agreementType;
  216 | export const AgreementCollection = agreementCollection;
> 217 | exports.Agreement = agreement;
```

Is `commonJs` supported in CRA? Is it possible to achieve this without `ejecting` the project?

Couldn't find any solution to it out on the web, just abandoned discussions.

A solution would be to migrate the NodeJs code to `es7` `import/export` but then I'll have to transpile that, and I would like to avoid this unnecessary step.

Any advice is much appreciated

Comment: Aren't you using es6 modules just above that on line 216? You could try changing line 217  to `export const Agreement = agreement`

Comment: No, I need to move everything to commonJs format, meaning I need to change line 215 and 216 to
```
exports.AgreementType = agreementType
exports.AgreementCollection = agreementCollection
```